# Exporting Test Cases and Shared Steps

Tags: tfs, export

Is there any way of exporting Test Cases and Shared Steps from one project to another in TFS 2012 using database queries?

I have tried TFS Integration tool, but it did not work as I expected, so I was wondering if there is any way of doing this by connecting to SQL Server and exporting all items directly from and to the databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't work directly in the database, because it is not supported by Microsoft and you could harm it a lot.

I used the TFS Integration Platform tools a lot for migrating TFS2010 projects, but never used it for TFS2012. My experience with that were good and it shouldn't be a problem to migrate all Test Cases and Shared Steps into another TeamProject. If you have the same Work Item Type Definitions in both projects, you don't need to create field mappings.

Another option would be to use Excel as "Export" and "Import" cache, but you might loose some information, because not everything could be shown in Excel, e.g. Steps of a TestCase, the history, Work Item Links.

If you are skilled in programming using TFS API, you could write your own small migrator, but this could be a lot of effort.

All in all the TFS Integration Platform should be the easiest and best way, so what have been your expectations that have not been fulfilled?

Comment: I ended up writing mu own tool using the TFS API. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A few days ago I needed an Excel testcase export for a newer version of TFS (TFS 2013). Turns out that there is still no export to Excel function built-in to TFS (in contrast to E-Mail and Printing) and the tools became incompatible over time.

But I found this Revival-Tool that seems to work:

https://github.com/jorupp/ExportTestCases

Just wanted to point that out even if it may not be directly related to this topic with TFS2012.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternative methods.

First export all Test cases using  ["Test case extractor."](http://testcaseextractor.codeplex.com)

Them import them in new project using  ["Test case import tool."](http://tcmimport.codeplex.com)

Comment: bro above link u provided are best ...... im saying first using http://testcaseextractor.codeplex.com/ you have to export all of your test casses to an exel sheet. and after tht using http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/ you can get back ur test casses on any project. thatz all

Comment: It was a general purpose, for writing better answers. I edited your your post to have the link inside and made an upvote ;)  I deleted my comments to clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the point mentioned above, for exporting the test cases you might find the below link more useful:
http://tfstestcaseexporttoexcel.codeplex.com/

I have given it a try and found it very useful and easy to use.